# How to calculate the car speed on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to show a car's speeds on iPhone in real time. What can I use?

Wouldn't using gps to calculate the car's speed take many seconds?

Comment: See the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582511/iphone-corelocation-how-to-get-the-most-accurate-speed

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate speed of our car using iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818902/how-to-calculate-speed-of-our-car-using-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an app called Speedometer and Map. I use Core Location to figure out where the user is, how far they move every second in miles, and then I convert this number to hours, and update it constantly.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't have much either. Look up tutorials about it and Apple's Documentation really helped. I'll give you some source code later when I get home if I remember.

Comment: Thanks, I'd appreciate it if you could my answer correct. Thanks!

Comment: The link is: http://www.chillysky.com/Speedometer.zip, tell me when you get it so that I can take it off. Hope this helps you!

Comment: Hello, i can't build the speedometer program in device what is the reason? I use ios 4.1.

Comment: What's the problem? Make sure you switch my certificates to yours.

Comment: When i build the program in device Alert view shows.

Answer (score 1):

If you implement a class that conforms to the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol, and set an instance of it as the `delegate` of a `CLLocationManager` object, your object will receive `-locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` messages after you call `-[CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation]`.  The `CLLocation` object you receive via that method has a `speed` property, which is the speed of the device in meters per second.  The frequency of updates can be controlled via `CLLocationManager`'s `distanceFilter` and `desiredAccuracy` properties.

Comment: For location parameter what can i use?

Comment: Can you tell me the following step of caculating the car speed program?