# How can I calculate my speed with an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate speed of our car using iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818902/how-to-calculate-speed-of-our-car-using-iphone)

How can I calculate my speed with an iPhone? For example, I might want to measure the speed of my car when driving. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.manager.delegate = self;
        [self.manager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"Speed = %f", newLocation.speed);
}
```

Comment: Using above code 'newLocation.speed', Getting Speed always as -1.0.

Answer (score 1):

1>You can use GPS
 Use the location services to get the latitude and longitude at a particular point of time and the you can get the same after a certain period of time say t.You can get the distance traveled from Latitude and longitude and divide it by the taken to get the speed

[See the Apple GPS Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#codinghowtos/DataManagement/_index.html)

2>You can use Accelerometer
if you start from a halt, you should be able to calculate the distance you travel
based off the acceleration over time of the device.

[See the Apple Accelerometer Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAcceleration_Class/Reference/UIAcceleration.html)